# Flutter error related with body_might_complete_normally

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm practicing flutter.

It's from some open source below. It makes error about body_might_complete_normally.

How can I work around it?

```
      Widget _buildBody(dynamic index) {

      switch(index) {
      case 0:
      return MainPage();
      case 1:
      return CatalogPage();
      case 2:
      return NotificationPage();
      case 3:
      return MorePage();
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the above case doesn't satisfy, widget will return nothing. You can include default on switch.

```dart
Widget _buildBody(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return MainPage();
    case 1:
      return CatalogPage();
    case 2:
      return NotificationPage();
    case 3:
      return MorePage();

    default: //this
      return Text("default");
  }
  // return Text("aa"); or this 
}
```

More about [switch-and-case](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case)